# lm324 current can draw safely

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-limiting

as we all know lm 324 consist 4 op-amp now the datasheet says current limitation like 40mA. Now I want to ask that whether 40mA for each op-amp or the sum of all 4 op-amp

Link to the datasheet [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm324.pdf).

Comment: You might want o link to the actual parts datasheet and point out the specific "current limitation" you are intrested in

Comment: The datasheet link is http://www.ti.com/product/LM324 ; I want to drive four 12v relay which may take upto 40mA each.

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan Normally would never use an op-amp to drive a relay. Technically you could, but it's just.. pointless.

Comment: @pipe why is that pointless? I can see that make sense if the opamp is configured as a comparator. Or when you used 3 out of the 4 opamps and want to use the 4th as a buffer to drive a relay (to save on extra parts).

Comment: @marcelm Sure, there are certain cases where it would be "ok" to use it. Using a generic opamp as a comparator is not great though, unless it's advertised as such.

Comment: @Siddhartha, I guess the point that's being made is this: "a person can technically use a pliers to pound nails into a piece of wood, but pounding nails into wood is not the job that pliers were designed to perform." The op amp is the "pliers," and the relay's coil is the "nail" you are trying to drive. To put it another way, use the right tool for the job. In your case, use a transistor driven between cutoff and saturation (BJT), or between cutoff and triode mode (MOSFET), rather than an op amp (which is not designed to function like a switch) to drive the relay's coil OFF/ON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some guessing, I conclude that you are looking at the *Short-circuit output current*. That is per output, but it is not the right figure to look at.

You want to look at I<sub>O</sub>, *Output current*, specified at typical -30/+20 mA at 25 °C, but only guaranteed -10/+5 mA at full temperature range. This is per output.

The *total* output current is limited by the total heat, and has to be calculated from the dissipated power, the thermal resistance, and the maximum allowed junction temperature.

---

I see that you want to drive a relay. This is normally done with a transistor, something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSjGbZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: by that means it is not totally safe. So it will be better to use transistor where base is op-amp output. by the way do you have any other better solution ????

Comment: A transistor is cheap and reliable, that's what I would suggest.

Comment: I designed a circuit where I used op-amp as a buffer and 2N2222A as a relay driver. I want to use this with arduino, now can you tell me without buffer if I directly use arduino pin as base of the transistor with require resistance if safe.

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan Yes, a digital output on an Arduino is perfectly capable of driving the base of a transistor for this purpose. I'm sure you will find a lot of examples on the internet.

Comment: yes I design rightly with 2N2222A, I am worried if transistor get into malfunctioning state then base and collector might get short-circuit and my arduino may fry. As per your opinion what is the best way to do this???? and thanx

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan: How to drive a transistor from an Arduino is covered in thousands and thousands of tutorials and applications. Please do some basic research.

Comment: @Siddhartha, can you clarify what you mean by "that means it is not totally safe" in your comment above? pipe's circuit example is a typical solution that is commonly used in real products. What element(s) of this circuit design do you perceive as "unsafe"?

Comment: For what it's worth, if you replace the BJT with a MOSFET you can dramatically reduce the amount of current the microcontroller must source through its DIO pins. Note that when using a MOSFET like this, you need to provide either a pull down or pull up resistor on the MOSFET's gate to define the desired default gate voltage when the microcontroller's DIO pin is not actively driving a voltage onto the MOSFET's gate--e.g., immediately after power on/reset a microcontroller usually configures its DIO pins as INPUTs, or it tri-states DIO output pins.

Answer (score 0):

> Maximum power dissipation is a function of \$T_{J(max)}\$, \$R_{θJA}\$, and \$T_A\$.

A PDIP has \$R_{θJA}= 80°C/W\$

$$P_D = \frac {T_{J(max)} - T_A}{R_{θJA}}= \frac {150°C - 25°C}{80°C/W} = 1.56W$$

Sinking 20mA (typical) at 25°C and 15V gives 0.3W, so 1.2W/package.

Not exactly sure where you got 40mA/Op-Amp, but at 15V, each op-amp would consume 0.6W and 2.4W/package.  This is greater than 1.56W, so not possible.

All this depends on your actual application but this should give you some idea.  Over the full range, each op-amp has minimum sink current of 5mA and source current of 10mA.

As pipe says, use a transistor to drive your relay.